# self.assertRaisesRegex not working, "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

Tags: python, unit-testing

My python unit test calls

```py
self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, "Missing price data for hids: {123}", self.idc_service.load_prices, date(2021, 2, 22), date(2021, 2, 23), [123])
```

which results in the error:

```py
Failure
Exception: Missing price data for hids: {123}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\Alin\Desktop\code\pyApps\pyApps\tests\services\TestIdcDataService.py", line 32, in test_missing_hid_prices
    self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, "Missing price data for hids: {123}", self.idc_service.load_prices, date(2021, 2, 22), date(2021, 2, 23), hids)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 1285, in assertRaisesRegex
    return context.handle('assertRaisesRegex', args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 178, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 217, in __exit__
    expected_regex.pattern, str(exc_value)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 135, in _raiseFailure
    raise self.test_case.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: "Missing price data for hids: {123}" does not match "Missing price data for hids: {123}"
```

The assertion error is confusing because those 2 strings match exactly. Is something going on with the message 'During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{} has special meaning for regexes, you need to escape them.

```
self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, r"Missing price data for hids: \{123\}", self.idc_service.load_prices, date(2021, 2, 22), date(2021, 2, 23), [123])
```